# c++: Eclipse cannot resolve imports from local classes

Tags: c++, eclipse

Apologies if this is a duplicate question. I did search thoroughly and could not find the answer.

I have 2 c++ .h files in the same directory. One of the classes inherits from the other, but Eclipse cannot resolve the symbol for the base class. Similar errors are happening throughout the project; but *base classes* seem to be resolvable from other directories, whereas derived classes cannot resolve the base class, which is located in the same directory. To clarify, I have the following directory structure:

```
src    
    dir
        classA.h
        classB.h
    otherDir
        classC.h
        classD.h
```

classA.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef OTHERDIR_A_H
#define OTHERDIR_A_H
class A {
    // A definition
};
#endif
```

classB.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef OTHERDIR_B_H
#define OTHERDIR_B_H
class B : public A { // Symbol 'A' could not be resolved
    // B definition
};
#endif
```

classC.h looks like this:

```
#include "D.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using std::cout; // resolves correctly
using dir::A; // resolves correctly
using dir::B; // Symbol 'B' could not be resolved
class C : public D { /* C definition */ };
```

I think that I have an Eclipse configuration issue, because when I run Make in the command line, it compiles. Here is the Makefile:

```
SRC=../../src
CPPFLAGS = -I$(SRC)
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = \
    -g -std=c++11 \
    -Wall \
    -Wno-unused-function

client1: always
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o client1 $(SRC)/otherDir/client1.cxx

clean:
        rm -f client1 *.o *~

always:
```

Under Properties->C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor, I have "Current toolchain: No ToolChain". However, the only option in the drop-down menu is "No ToolChain", so I can't choose another toolchain. I have not been able to find out how to install or add a toolchain to Eclipse on OSX. I believe I have the XCode toolchain installed.

Any suggestions on how to resolve local imports?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you including the header files in your code?

Comment: Oh and I think you think the using statement does something different to what it actually does. You're getting meaning (6) from here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace . You seem to expect it to be like 'using' in C# or 'import' in java.

Comment: James, I am not using "#include classA" in classB.h for two reasons. First, classA and classB are starter code for an assignment which I am not intended to modify. Second, including "#include classA" does not solve the resolve problem.
I believe it is not a problem with my code actually, since the code compiles fine using Make.

the "using" statements in classC.h were also part of the starter code. Probably they would work if classB actually compiled in the first place (remember that "using dir::A" also works in ClassC)

Comment: `#include "classA.h"` would be the correct statement, `#include classA` won't compile. I suspect the starter code is wrong. If it doesn't include "classA.h" anywhere, how is it supposed to know what A is? I'm going to guess that if you check the Makefile, you'll find that it force-includes all the header files in the command it provides to whichever toolchain you're using. What compiler are you using? It might have an extension that results in the using statement making some sense. It's certainly not valid C++ (well unless there's a 'dir' namespace).

Comment: Sorry, I meant `include "classA.h"`.If I command-click on `include "classA.h"`, it does bring me to the code for classA. However, the line `"class B : public A {"` still does not resolve.

I am using g++ for make; not sure which compiler, if any, Eclipse is using.
'dir' is a namespace.

Comment: g++ is the compiler. make is another program that automates the compiling and linking of many files.

Comment: yes, I mean Make is using g++ as the compiler.

Comment: Is B actually in the 'dir' namespace, or a different namespace?

Comment: yes, both A and B are in the 'dir' namespace.

Comment: It might be worthwhile for you to post a more complete code example; otherwise we're just going to go back and forth playing twenty questions to try and figure out what's wrong (for example, it's impossible to tell that 'dir' is a namespace from the code you've got up there). It'd be helpful if you included your Makefile as well, or at least enough of it that we can figure out why it's building with make but not Eclipse. Most of the reasons I can come up with for that situation would imply different errors, so I'm a tiny bit confused.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize that dir is a namespace at first, or that dir being a namespace was important. I posted the Makefile in the original post, but I don't think any of the other code is relevant. A few weeks ago I had the exact same code working fine in eclipse, so I am still confident it is an eclipse problem. Thanks for your help, but at this point I think I will just give up on Eclipse/XCode and develop using Sublime and Make.

Comment: It's possibly relevant because we don't know how those headers are getting included - and they must be getting included, somehow, or nothing would build. Any misconfiguration in Eclipse should result in it complaining about missing headers, not just missing definitions, and presumably you'd tell us if you were getting that error. This line in the Makefile is intriguing: `CPPFLAGS = -I$(SRC)`. It's adding $(SRC) to the include search path. If there's no equivalent in Eclipse, that'd explain it, but then you'd be getting missing-include errors.

Comment: Oh also your example code doesn't have semicolons after the class definitions - is that a feature of the actual code, or just your example? That is, `class A {};`, not `class A {}`.

Comment: On a whim, I added `otherDir::` in front of some cases where otherDir's contents were not resolved. (e.g. change `public A` to `public otherDir::A`). This has fixed most of the errors and made eclipse useable despite a couple other unresolved methods.

Answer (score 0):

On a whim, I added `otherDir::` in front of some cases where otherDir's contents were not resolved. (e.g. change `public A` to `public otherDir::A`). This has fixed most of the errors and made eclipse useable despite a couple other unresolved methods.

Comment: If that is the complete contents of your files, A and B are not, in fact, in a namespace. client1.cxx's include order might be relevant in some way. Your directory structure has zero impact on the code. `using dir::A;` just means "When I say 'A', I might mean 'dir::A'", NOT "A is defined in some file under directory 'dir'"